# How to select data from a table with fixed difference between two columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-arithmetic

I want to query a MySQL table which has to columns "generationUtc" and "Utc" and I want to query only the data for which the difference between "generationUtc" and "Utc" is one day. For example I want only data that has generationUtc = 2020-07-21 and Utc = 2020-07-22, which is one day later. But I want this for all dates available.

So this is both a question related to dates in SQL, but also on extracting data with certain conditions on different columns.

I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM database
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM (generatedUtc - Utc)) = '1'
```

but this does not seem to work. I found a lot of posts on how to extract the difference between two columns as a new column, but not on how to extract data with a condition on the **difference** of two columns directly.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide examples!  What does "1 day" mean to you

Comment: What's the database? SQL is just a language, and time functions vary wildly between engines.

Comment: It is MySQL. I am sorry I did not know I am not really that familiair with SQL.I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is MySQL-tagged - so

```
SELECT * 
FROM database
WHERE DATEDIFF(Utc, generatedUtc) = 1
```

This needs both columns to be defined as DATE datatype. If they're DATETIME or TIMESTAMP then

```
SELECT * 
FROM database
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(Utc), DATE(generatedUtc)) = 1
```